# How to convert une bitmap (opencv ) in imageProcessor (imageJ )

Tags: android, imagej

I have a bitmap bm1 and I want to convert to an ImageProcessor, imageProcessor is a type of ImageJ library.

```
 Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(newImage.width(), newImage.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(outputthreshlod1, bm1);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm1);
```

Comment: Have you found out any answer for this ?